# Telerik unknown Error , unknown Version

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a vs application i don't know what the version used is, but i used Q2 2010. 
Please help me to find a version or get solution of this error .

1- Index is read only.

```
radGridViewContainerStock.Columns["Product_Name"].Index = 1;
```

2- row info doesn't have CellElement Property and VisualElement.

```
private void radGridViewContainerStock_ViewCellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
 {
     e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["Discrepancy"].CellElement.ForeColor = radGridViewTripStock.Rows[e.CellElement.RowIndex].VisualElement.ForeColor;
}
```

Comment: You should probably ask this at [Telerik's Board](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview.aspx)...

Comment: i already ask there on this link  http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/general-discussions/unknown-error-unknown-version.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1- Index is read only.

> radGridViewContainerStock.Columns["Product_Name"].Index = 1;

answer :
 this is on Old versions Q1 2010 and older but from version Q2 to now 
to order Coulmn use Move Function

> radGridViewContainerStock.Columns.Move(radGridViewContainerStock.Columns["Product_Name"].Index , 1);

2- cellelement

```
 e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["Discrepancy"].CellElement.ForeColor = radGridViewTripStock.Rows[e.CellElement.RowIndex].VisualElement.ForeColor;
```

it move to Style proberty we can use :

> e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["Discrepancy"].Style.ForeColor = ...

Thank you.